# Pass local data from 1 script to another

Tags: r, shiny, connection

A little background so you can understand the problem/environment:

I am building a complex shiny app. The first step is to take in User Input: it takes a list of selections possible and filters a large data set down based on the UI. From there it takes this locally filtered data set and needs to call a function with it to do a whole bunch of calculations, and then return the results.

This is what I would like to do: I want to have the app and this function in separate scripts since the function alone is over 300 lines of code. Currently they are in separate scripts, however, they are not linked together yet.

The structure of my `server` in shiny is:

```
output$plot <- renderPlot({
  # Filter based on UI to result in a data set called d2
  # Here I would like to call my function
```

The structure of my function is:

```
data <- fread("local_path.csv") 

my_function <- function(){
  # A ton of calculations using data set loaded above
}
# Call to function
my_function()
```

Right now if I go into my `server` and call `source("my_function_script.R")` the script will run with the data I load in within the script.

My question is how do I send the data to the other script? I can easily run the source line and then call the function in the shiny app, but how do I send the filtered data over to the other script?

The other thing to keep in mind is after these calculations are done it produces a plot, if the user now wants to change their input the app lets them, then it re-filters the data and has to call the function again to recalculate everything to be able to graph a new plot.

I know one solution (not a good solution though) would be to output a csv after filtering the data and then set that file path in my other script, however, since this is a huge chunk of data (even with filtering) this would slow down the process tremendously.

Any thoughts and help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, when you say "how do I send the data to the other script" you mean by "other" the script that defines the function - the one that currently begins with `data <- fread(...)`.

The answer is that you don't send data from `server.R` to that script; and don't call the function from that script either, just define it there.  You should:

- delete the call to the function `my_function()` from the script that defines the function
- add a `d2` argument to the function
- at the top of your `server.R` (ie before `shinyServer(function(input, output))`, call `source(my_function_definition.R)` so the original full dataset is read in once and the function is defined once
- define `d2` as a reactive object within `server.R` (I'm presuming you're already doing this) `d2 <- reactive({definition code here; return(d2)})`
- call `my_function(d2())` when you need to in the `server.R` file, passing the result to whatever needs those results to produce some output.

Functions should take inputs and return outputs.